# How to REGEXP_REPLACE special character

Tags: regex, oracle, regexp-replace

I am having issue with following regex

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE(declinereasondesc, '(.+)(£)(\d+)', '\1\3 (GBP)') as r from DECLINEREASON t
```

it does not match following rows

```
Too expensive : By less than £100
Too expensive : By more than £200
```

Expected outcome

```
Too expensive : By less than 100 (GBP)
Too expensive : By more than 200 (GBP)
```

**EDIT:**

screenshot for non-believers
[image]

Comment: is working here http://regex101.com/r/lZ5mN8/34

Comment: What is the output you are getting? Your regex works fine for me

Comment: @arunb2w it does not match row so nothing changed (`Too expensive : By less than £100`)

Comment: @vks I know http://regex101.com/r/dZ1vT6/10#pcre does not work in oracle.

Comment: @LIUFA - It is working fine here 
**select REGEXP_REPLACE('Too expensive : By less than £100', '(.+)(£)(\d+)', '\1\3 (GBP)') as r from dual;**
I think your source string is not what you are expecting

Comment: @arunb2w added screenshot.

Comment: @vks added screenshot

Comment: @LIUFA - Is it working fine when you give the string as constant in the form of dual?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65206/discussion-between-arunb2w-and-liufa).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out myself problem is `£` as I am sure everyone suspected

Solution contains two steps first is to get symbol code, even if you copy paste `£` into `select ascii() from dual` it does not fly. You have to select the symbol like following to get correct code.

```
select ascii(substr(declinereasondesc, 30,1)) from DECLINEREASON t
where declinereasonid = 7;
```

In my case it gave `49827`

then

```
select REGEXP_REPLACE(declinereasondesc, '(.+)('||chr(49827)||')(\d+)', '\1\3 (GBP)') from DECLINEREASON t;
```

and only then it works. 
[image]

Comment: What is the oracle character set in your database?I think it is due to NLS_CHARACTERSET parameter in your DB

Comment: @arunb2w Could be `SELECT value$ FROM sys.props$ WHERE name = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET' ;` gives me `ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
`. So can't confirm.

Comment: Can you try this
**select * 
from v$nls_parameters 
where parameter in ('NLS_CHARACTERSET','NLS_LANGUAGE');**

Comment: I am happy that you solved your problem. But ascii value of £ is 163. I would suggest you to change your character set to avoid these kind of problems in future. ASCII reference :: http://www.ascii-code.com/

Comment: @arunb2w If only I could... :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65208/discussion-between-arunb2w-and-liufa).