# Oracle declare select into update statement does not work

Tags: regex, oracle, select-into, regexp-replace

I [had an issue where due to database charset special characters would get weird codes assigned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27016064/how-to-regexp-replace-special-character) to them, then by getting `select ascii(substr(declinereasondesc, 30,1)) from DECLINEREASON t
where declinereasonid = 7;` I got code (49827) for `£` in db charset. I then tried to update the records in database.

Problem that I am getting is that data does not get saved to DB or `selecting into` value to `varchar2(6);` somehow changes it and it does not match `REGEXP_REPLACE` any-more.

It did error when I tried using `varchar2(1)` which should value, which could be a hint.

```
declare c varchar2(6);
begin 
select ascii(substr(declinereasondesc, 30,1)) into c from DECLINEREASON t
where declinereasonid = 7;
begin 
  update DECLINEREASON set declinereasondesc = REGEXP_REPLACE(declinereasondesc, '(.+)('||c||')(\d+)', '\1\3 (GBP)');
  commit;
  end;
end;
/
commit;
```

**Update:**  tried `declare c number;` no errors but didn't update values ether

Comment: No `where` clause in the `update` statement?!?

Comment: @ammoQ don't need it, regex_replace that does not match returns it's input value.

Comment: but that still means the update statement still affects all rows in `DECLINEREASON`, which might cause unwanted side effects (performance penalty, triggers firing, locks ...) even if the update per se has no effect

Comment: @ammoQ you're absolutely correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one was caused by me being stupid - forgot to wrap `c` in `chr(c)`.

```
declare c number;
begin 
select ascii(substr(declinereasondesc, 30,1)) into c from DECLINEREASON t
where declinereasonid = 7;
begin 
  update DECLINEREASON set declinereasondesc = REGEXP_REPLACE(declinereasondesc, '(.+)('||chr(c)||')(\d+)', '\1\3 (GBP)');
  commit;
  end;
end;
/
  commit;
```